# Как бесплатно уменьшить вес большого количества картинок?

Tags: веб-программирование, изображения, img, оптимизация-сайтов

На сайте очень много картинок (приблизительно 25 тысяч. Это крупный интернет-магазин). Нужно как-то уменьшить их размер, потому что они занимают много места.

Мне нравится, как это делает Tinypng. Но бесплатная версия не подходит для такого большого количества картинок.

Я пробовал программу FastStone (там есть пакетная обработка), но она меняет регистр расширения файла (jpg, png...) - можно выбрать, либо менять на маленький, либо на большой. А оставить тот, который был, нельзя (может, у меня некоторые картинки с большим регистром, а некоторые - с маленьким. Может, вообще с разным регистром, например: .Jpg). На Windows регистр не имеет значения. А вот на Linux имеет. И после пережатия картинок может возникнуть такая ситуация, что папка с картинками станет даже тяжелее, т.к. картинок стало больше.

Пробовал XnConvert, менял степень сжатия (ставил на максимум). Вес картинки если и уменьшался, то незначительно. А иногда даже увеличивался. Как я понял, поставить условие - если вес увеличился, то не сохранять картинку, нельзя. Да и зачем мне такая программа, если она практически не уменьшает вес.

Можно через XnConvert сначала пакетно уменьшить размер, а потом увеличить. Картинка будет весить меньше. Но, по-моему, это костыль, из-за которого картинка может стать размазанной. Tinypng как-то иначе работает.

Какой программой воспользоваться, чтобы бесплатно уменьшить вес такого большого кол-ва картинок?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-compress-images-using-python-and-pil/

Comment: Там скорее всего не степень сжатия, а уровень качества. Т.е. надо поставить поменьше, а не максимум.

Comment: У крупного магазина нет денег на прогу? =).
Есть варианты но они вас очень испугают.

1)Перефоткать все без фона, только объекты оставить, есть форматы картинок не хранят фон.
2)вариант пункта 1 вырезать фон у готовых…оч муторно.
3)Еще более радикальный вариант это попробовать векторизацию, т.е. из растровых изображений сделать векторные естественно с потерей деталей…никуда не деться. Нужен эксперимент на то как сожмет и как выглядит потом.
4)самый компактный формат это хранить алгоритм создания объектов…почти нереальный практически.

Comment: А разве gulp не умеет сжимать картинки ?

Comment: Я использую - https://compressnow.com/ - с 65% сжатием. Для оптимизации изображений попробуйте https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/images